# Quartz composer HLS video trouble

Tags: macos, video-streaming, quicktime, http-live-streaming, quartz-composer

I have a Quartz Composer Version 4.5 (141.5) on my MacOS 10.7.2 and a QuickTime Framework version 7.6.6.

All I want is just render test HLS video stream using QC. HLS stream is just an apple test stream: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

So, I've created a sketch:

[image: my QC sketch]

(It's a MovieImporter patch covered by stream url)

Next all I can see in QC Viewer is just a blank screen and infinite debug log:

```
17:08:42.233 ["Movie Importer" @ "Macro Patch"] > Execution failed at time 2802.003
17:08:42.313 ["Movie Importer" @ "Macro Patch"] > Failed retrieving image from movie <QTMovie: 0x7fd992e02d00 time scale = 600, duration = 2184000, rate = 0.000000, tracks = { 0x7fd992f1a0e0 0x7fd992e205c0 0x7fd992e12310 0x7fd9928b11b0 0x7fd9928a7990 }> (error (null))
```

Also I've tried to launch same sketch on MacOS 10.6.8, QC 4.0(103.1), but unsuccessfully.

What the problem? Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to your Quartz Composer version adn Mac OS X Lion.

Try downloading the new version, as said here : http://kineme.net/forum/General/QCFramework148MovieImporterpatch